# Removing a .click but still attaching a function to an input - Quiz fade out on input

Tags: jquery, input, submit, fadeout

The code is working!!

I now have a quiz that does the following:  A user picks one the radio buttons.  On submit the selected answer fades in. Thanks to everyone who contributed to the answer.

** The submit button does not submit to a database or other scripting language

```
// **************  Quiz 2 (right side) ********************//
var selectAnswer = function(){  
var answer = $("input[name='radio2']:checked").val();
    console.log(answer);
         if(answer=='correct2') {
            $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
                 $("#correct2").fadeIn();             
              });
          $("#wrong1a").hide();
          }
    if(answer=='wrong1a') {
         $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
             $("#wrong1a").fadeIn(); }
         )};

    if(answer=='wrong2a') {
         $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
             $("#wrong2a").fadeIn(); }
             )};

    if(answer=='wrong4a') {
         $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
             $("#wrong4a").fadeIn(); 
         }); 

        $("#correct2").hide();

        }
        //end of of selectAnswer\

// end of of selectAnswer
};
$(document).ready(function(){  // when the submit button is pressed, run selectAnswer function
    $("#submitButton2").click(selectAnswer);

 $("#correct2").hide();
$("#wrong1a").hide();

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="inputs_bg4"><input name="radio2" type="radio" value="wrong1a"></div></td>
<div class="inputs_bg4"><input name="radio2" type="radio" value="wrong2a"></div></td>
<div class="inputs_bg3"><input name="radio2" type="radio" value="correct2"></div></td>
<div class="inputs_bg4"><input name="radio2" type="radio" value="wrong4a"></div></td>
```

Comment: If the question is answered, please mark it as answered so that future Googlers don't pass it by.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete `$("input[name='radio2']").click(function() {}` around `selectAnswer` and use `var answer = $("input[name='radio2']:checked").val();` on the first line.

Comment: Although efficient, a potential problem with this implementation is that that won't get called whenever the user clicks on the radio buttons, which I think was a want.  If LaToya is just running on the submit of the form your solution is definitely the better one.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Perhaps I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Also, @Interstellar_Coder took a similar approach, which made me realize a bug in what I posted. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Using .change() on the list of radio buttons should fix this.

```
$("input[name=radio2]").bind("change", function(){});
```

Make sure you put this binding somewhere that gets read after the radio buttons are loaded but before the user would have a chance to actually manipulate the radio buttons.

Edit:  If you're just trying to only run the function upon selection, I've stubbed out a (untested) solution below.

```
function selectAnswer(radio_name){
    val = $("input[name='" + radio_name + "']").val();
    //Do what you will
}

$("#submitbutton").bind("click", function(){  selectAnswer("radio2")   });
```

Comment: This solution will result in the change action being fired when a user clicks a radio button, but only after the submit button has been pressed. Also, if the submit button has been pressed multiple times, this will result in the action being executed multiple times.

Comment: I think you may be mistaken here, I'm only binding to the radio buttons (example http://jsfiddle.net/cDanq/1/)

Comment: Yes, understood. But my point is that in the original post, the handler wasn't added until click. Are you suggesting that be changed as well? It's not clear from your answer.

Comment: Ahhh, I can almost hear the echo of that giant whoosh that went over my head.  Yes I was assuming that the poster would know not to put this binding in the submit action.  I'll update accordingly, thank you.

Comment: This will only fade in the correct answer if i change to another radio button.  The submit button doesn't work. Is there something else I can use?

Comment: LOL...I am reading the comments... I am fairly new to JQuery, so most likely I did exactly what I should not do..

Comment: You'll have to bind to the submit button as well.  I may still be confused; your ideal program would have the same function run on selection of a radio button and on submission on the form?  Or did you want to simply get the value of the radio buttons?  I'm starting to think I've been on the wrong track, and have edited my answer to also show a solution for the later.

Comment: I am not sure where I should place the new function.  I am modifying my code above.

Comment: LaToya, can you please elaborate for future Googlers?

Comment: The quiz does not change until the user hits the submit button.  The submit button is not really submitting anything, it's just invoking the function on the radio button.

Comment: Alright, then my edited version should work for you, and I apologize Michael as my correction on your post was in err.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectAnswer = function(){         
  var answer = $("input[name='radio2']:checked").val();   
     if(answer=='correct2') {
        $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
             $("#correct2").fadeIn();             
          });
      $("#wrong1a").hide();
      }
    if(answer=='wrong1a') {
         $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
             $("#wrong1a").fadeIn(); }
         )};

    if(answer=='wrong2a') {
         $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
             $("#wrong2a").fadeIn(); }
             )};

    if(answer=='wrong4a') {
         $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
             $("#wrong4a").fadeIn(); 
         }); 

        $("#correct2").hide();

        }
        });//end of of selectAnswer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/ueWgD/)):

```
    $("#submitButton2").click(function(){ //I would just add a click handler to the submit button
        var answer = $("input:checked").val(); //this finds the value of the selected radio button
console.log(answer);
     if(answer=='correct2') {
        $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
             $("#correct2").fadeIn();             
          });
      $("#wrong1a").hide();
      }
    if(answer=='wrong1a') {
         $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
             $("#wrong1a").fadeIn(); }
         )};

    if(answer=='wrong2a') {
         $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
             $("#wrong2a").fadeIn(); }
             )};

    if(answer=='wrong4a') {
         $("#quiz2").fadeOut(function(){
             $("#wrong4a").fadeIn(); 
         }); 
        $("#correct2").hide();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
$('#reset').click(function(){
    $('#quiz2').show();
    $('#answers div').hide();    
});
```

Comment: This does not work.  for some reason, it doesn't even show what answer is in the console.log.  I do like the idea of putting an event on the submit button.